# How not to display two same JSON properties in one item by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file, saved locally, on my local drive (still don't know how to use server). In that JSON file I have an array of objects, something like this:

```
 [
    {
       "id" : 1,
        "movieStill " : "<img src='imgsMovie/MovieFolder/Transformers/StillPhotoBackground.jpg'/>",

    },
    {
       "id" : 2,
        "movieStill " :" <img src='imgsMovie/MovieFolder/Lord of The rings/StillPhotoBackground2.jpg'/>",

    },
 ]
```

I have two objects, with different ID's and different imgs, under the same property name. Now, when I click an item with id 1, I want to show the background image.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("js/appjson.json", function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (var key in data[i]) {
                if (key === "movieStill") {
                    $('.MovieInfo').append(
                        "<div class='imgStill'>" + data[i].movieStill + "</div>"
                    )
                } else {

                }
            }
        }
    })
});
```

I want to display the image that corresponds to the clicked item's ID, but the above code is displaying both images.  How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, it's missing quotes, and the javascript doesn't seem to match the JSON at all, for instance there are no `movieStill` keys etc?

Comment: I know, i wrote JSON  as an example, movieStill, is  the img

Comment: *"I want to check if the property in those objects exist,..."* You don't need a loop for that. Just do `if ("movieStill" in data[i]) {...` or `if (data[i].hasOwnProperty("movieStill")) {...`

Comment: It's displaying 2 images because you're iterating the object and telling it to append a new image for every object that has `movieStill`. You're talking about clicking on something to display an image, but I don't know what that thing is. Are they elements that are already in the DOM? Are you creating them in the same loop? As for the images, do you know how to use CSS styles to hide them?

Comment: try changing the condition in if loop- `if ( key.id === YOUR_VARIABLE ){
                $( '.MovieInfo' ).append(
                    "<div class='imgStill'>" +  key.movieStill + "</div>"
                ) ;}` and pass YOUR_VARIABLE as 1 or 2 as needed

Comment: I have 20 objects with  ids from 1 do 20. How to get the the id when an item is clicked and show a img from that id?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.getJSON( "js/collectie.json", function(data) {
    jsoncollectie = data;
})

$( "#collectie" ).click(function(){

    console.log("click detected");
    var data_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    console.log(thumb_id);
    console.log(jsoncollectie);

    for(var i = 0; i < jsoncollectie.length; i++){

        if(jsoncollectie[i].id == data_id){
            $( '.MovieInfo' ).append(
                    "<div class='imgStill'>" + jsoncollectie[i].img  + "</div>"
                )
        }   

    }

});


});
```

please try this way, I hope this will help you

Comment: Where should i put  click function? Because i already can click on an item from index html page and it brings me to another html page. Where i want to show the image based on clicked id

Comment: click function need to be there in index.html related script.  showing image is your requirement, anyway you can display that in index page.